# Can WSL2 use the Android SDK installed on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-sdk

I have the android-sdk installed on Windows, and I have exported its path to the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` WSL environment variable. Should WSL be able to compile my projects using the SDK that's installed on Windows? It says my SDK is corrupted when I try to build my Cordova project.  Could this be the cause?  I've uninstalled/reinstalled the same version of the SDK and a few other, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSL can run Windows programs but they will be run as normal Windows processes. I'm not familiar with the program that you are trying to run, but be aware that it is equivalent to running it on Windows.

You can ensure your interoperability works by calling `notepad.exe` from Linux and seeing notepad start. If this works, then your problem is specific to the application you're running.

Compiling in one OS with another OS's tools seems unlikely to work, I'm not familiar enough with Android's SDK to comment any further.

Comment: I will use a vm instead of this weird setup, then. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

While Ubuntu on WSL can *execute* most any Windows binary, keep in mind that Windows binaries still won't understand *Linux* paths, processes, environment variables, and some other configuration items/files that Ubuntu provides.  For this reason, I typically recommend that you run Windows programming tools such as the Android SDK from Windows.  If you want to use the *Linux* version of the Android SDK, you can do that from Ubuntu under WSL.

For instance, you mention that you exported `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, but a Windows process started from inside Ubuntu/WSL will not see that *Linux* environment variable.

You can fix this by using the [`WSLENV` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems#share-environment-variables-between-windows-and-wsl-with-wslenv) feature of WSL (original [devblog announcement with more detail](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/)).

That means, for the *Windows* version of the Android SDK to see `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, you need to add that variable name to the `WSLENV` variable.

For example:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='C:\path\to\SDK\`
export WSLENV="$WSLENV:ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
```

While this might solve *part* of the problem, note that you must use the *Windows* path format above instead of the WSL/Linux path (`/mnt/c/path/...`).  This is because you are running a *Windows* process.

These issues *could* in theory all be worked around with things like `wslpath`, `WSLENV`, and other features, but again, for tools like this, I typically would recommend:

- Using the Windows version of the toolchain (editor, commandline, SDK, tools, etc.)
- Or using all-Linux versions of the toolchain.

Mix and match only in (a) simple cases, or (b) if you know how to troubleshoot and solve any issues that come up.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes things clearer !