# Commands work in Powershell but not Ubuntu in Windows terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Commands like npx and npm are working when I run them in Powershell. When I type the same commands into the same terminal on the same computer but on Ubuntu, they do not work. Why is this? How do I get them to work?

[image]

Comment: You've installed the windows version of npm? Ubuntu is Linux, not Windows. So you'll need to install the Linux version.

Comment: So I have to install things twice on the same computer?

Comment: Please realize that Ubuntu as well as other Linux operating systems is different from Windows. It means that tools must be made in different ways in order to communicate with the operating system. The operating system is a layer between the machine language (set of instructions) and the tools (you mention npx and npm).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can WSL2 use the Android SDK installed on Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440008/can-wsl2-use-the-android-sdk-installed-on-windows)